# Connecting a 2009 Macbook to a TV with video and sound output

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, video, displayport, television

I would like to connect my late 2009 white Macbook to my TV, with support for video and sound.

I thought I could use the Mini DisplayPort for that purpose, but unfortunately, [Apple's website](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4241?viewlocale=en_US) says that:

> These Apple computers supply only video signals over Mini DisplayPort:
>
> (...)
>   MacBook (Late 2009)

I found [this product](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0031QH1BG) from another question on Stack, but considering the price and the negative comments of that product, I'm wondering if there are cheaper/better solutions?

My TV is a recent Samsung TV with classic ports (USB, HDMI...).

Answer (score 1):

The product you are considering retails for $69.99, Amazon is showing me one for $50 + shipping. This type of equipment is generally very sensitive to movement, easy to damage and easy to get annoyed with. Consider the manufacturing cost of that product, against how much you will pay. It seems the markup outweighs the value.

Have you considered Apple TV? You get a dedicated, more reliable, better device for $100, and it takes up less room than a MacBook combined with a cable adapter that looks like a homemade incendiary device.

Verdict: Buy an Apple TV.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well, I'm not particularly fond of spending $100 just to watch movies from my computer. I already do that with my external drive. I was just wondering if there was some sort of $15 cable which could just do that.

Comment: The cheapest solution is to use external speakers, or the Macbook's speakers, in combination with a simple Mini DisplayPort cable hooked up to the tv.

A cheap $15 cable that combines DisplayPort with audio is likely to be even less reliable than the $70 cable you have identified.

Answer (score 0):

There are very few options for non-AirPlay casting to a non-Apple TV device. But I have found this:

Mirror for Samsung TV 4+

by AirBeamTV BV

(Get the free trial 1st to see if it works, link is in the apps description)

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mirror-for-samsung-tv/id1107644799?mt=12&ign-itsct=1107644799-1107644799&ign-itscg=0176&ign-mpt=uo%3D4

You'll need the Audio Driver as well (link is in the apps description).

The only caveat is to make sure your Samsung TV qualifies:

> This works on any Samsung Smart TV from the 2012 models onward. Which
>   model year do you have? You can see that by looking at the middle
>   letter in your model type (on the back of your Samsung TV).
>
> E = 2012 F = 2013 H = 2014 J = 2015 K = 2016 M = 2017
>
> For instance:
>
> UE55_E_S8000 = 2012. UE78_H_U8500L = 2014.

Hopefully this works for your 2009 MacBook.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question has risen from the ashes, @OP had the right idea. Before I had a Mac with audio over the video port, I used an adapter like this to get simple HDMI out: 
https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=5969

I now have a 2012 MacBook Pro which does do audio over the mini display port, so I use a much simpler adapter now. But if anyone else needs this kind of thing, that adapter is the way to go.